# How many rules elastalert can load? Limit of the rules for ElastAlert

Tags: elastalert, elastalert2

Loading how many rule files is advisable with a single node elastalert?
What is the hard limit for setting up the rules ?
I have gone through following link but didnt get any answer
https://gitter.im/Yelp/elastalert?at=56de6014b0cc3f1b4150f00e

Can I load around 1000 alert rules in a single go?
how will it perform  if no of config files will increase upto 1000 ?

Comment: I dont think there would be an issue with the number of YAML files you ingest into the rules directory from a run time perspective, the problem might happen when they are executed as they will be executed within the configured buffer interval. the question then becomes will your elastic search setup be able to handle the 1000 query hit every buffer time? and the answer it depends on the query complexity and your setup specs .. i wouldn't recommend going this path because its prone to issues.

Comment: also you may wanna take a alook at this page https://discuss.elastic.co/t/concurrent-search-request-to-elasticsearch/21539